# What is a field effect rectifier diode

Tags: diodes, rectifier, schottky

ST offers what they call field-effect rectifier diodes. Does anybody know what that actually is and how they work?

Application wise it seems very similar to a Schottky diode (low voltage drop,) but apparently it's some proprietary technology. Here is a [datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/FERD40U45CG-TR-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-21068888.pdf)

Comment: https://patents.google.com/patent/US8148748B2/en