# What is a field effect rectifier diode (FERD) and what is it used for?

Tags: diodes, components, rectifier, component-selection

I was searching DigiKey for a particular type of diode, and found [field effect rectifier diode (FERD)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?s=N4IgjCBcoJwGxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzACxxw0gC6hADgC5QgDKrATgJYA7AOYgAvoQC0AJkQgUkXgFcCxMiACsjcSAkxZ8pSpKRyEBqO0JoIPgBMOEsAAYILdpBAhCrAJ7NcHOjYKBZAA). What are they used for?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/611336/what-is-a-field-effect-rectifier-diode

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but the I thought patent reference in the other question was useful.  They're basically an alternative to Schottkys with possibly lower leakage in some applications.

Comment: Here's some info from ST that may be helpful: https://www.stmicroelectronics.com.cn/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/promotional_material/flyer/group0/c1/f1/cc/fe/5f/b1/40/b4/Field-Effect_Rectifier_Diodes/files/FLFERD601000521.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.FLFERD601000521.pdf

Comment: @JohnD -- That was very helpful. Thank you! Since the other question wasn't answered, I think I'll take a stab at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

Apparently, the FERD is a technology all its own, a higher-priced higher-quality (lower forward voltage, lower leakage), or as one later-quoted source says, "achieves the best in class VF/IR trade-off for a given silicon surface".

A field-effect rectifier diode can replace Schottky diodes in a power converter, significantly improving the efficiency of the converter.

### Quick Example

The lowest-current example I could find is the ($0.98 @ one at DigiKey as of July 26, 2022)
[50V 15A Surface Mount PowerFlat™ (FERD) Field Effect Rectifier Diode FERD15S50DJF-TR](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/FERD15S50DJF-TR/4756093)

[image]

Above, you can see that this is in the fast-recovery class, which means that it's good for SMPS, including DC-DC converters. It also has a forward voltage of 480mV at 10A, but even less at lower currents. In some cases, it seems to have about half the forward voltage. The DigiKey video referenced later states that this Schottky diode alternative can be an acceptable alternative to more complicated synchronous solutions, and I say that if you're trying to make Gold- or Platinum-level 80-Plus certifications, then this is a good tool to have in your tool belt, especially if you're just below a cut-off and have to find a way to nudge the design another percent or two.

### More Detail

There is some information on this site already at the following link: [What is a field effect rectifier diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/611336/146624), including a link to a patent, and a datasheet, but you may find the following information more accessible:

Some very helpful information was given by John D, at [Field-Effect Rectifier Diodes - Advantageously Replace Schottky KW Three-Channel](https://www.stmicroelectronics.com.cn/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/promotional_material/flyer/group0/c1/f1/cc/fe/5f/b1/40/b4/Field-Effect_Rectifier_Diodes/files/FLFERD601000521.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.FLFERD601000521.pdf)

where it says:

> Design safe, compact, and affordable power supplies
>
> ST’s new 60V and 100V field-effect rectifier diodes (FERD) help power
> converter designers reach higher efficiency and increased density at
> levels that were not achievable using traditional Schottky solutions.
>
> In regards to power density, our new FERD dice are much smaller than
> Schottky ones and can be easily integrated into smaller packages. For
> example, a 20A or higher FERD diode housed in a DPAK package reduces
> by a factor of 3 the PCB surface occupied by a Schottky diode of the
> same current rating housed in a D²PAK package.
>
> Of course, the application’s overall electrical performance is
> maintained and often improved using FERD diodes.
>
> In addition to the power integration benefits, the potential positive
> economic impact of using a less expensive package solution must be
> taken into account.
>
> Moreover, ST’s patented FERD technology exhibits a much better
> controlled leakage current, with a lower thermal coefficient than
> standard Schottky diodes. Therefore, developers will appreciate an
> easier thermal design, with reduced thermal runaway risks, and the
> associated improved reliability

[image]

At [BDTIC - FERD20H100S：100 V field-effect rectifier diode]([http://www.bdtic.com/en/st/FERD20H100S]](http://www.bdtic.com/en/st/FERD20H100S%5D) it says,

> The device is based on a proprietary technology that achieves the best
> in class VF/IR trade-off for a given silicon surface. This 100 V
> rectifier has been optimized for use in confined applications where
> both efficiency and thermal performance are key. With a lower
> dependency of leakage current (IR) and forward voltage (VF) in
> function of temperature, the thermal runaway risk is reduced. It is
> highly recommended to be used in adapters and chargers.
>
> Key Features:
> ST advanced rectifier process
> Stable leakage current over reverse voltage
> Reduced leakage current
> Low forward voltage drop
> High frequency operation

### A DigiKey Video

There is a [video at DigiKey that is a quick watch (about a minute - 1:08).](https://www.digikey.com/api/videos/videoplayer/smallplayer/5793758328001)

Comment: Very interesting, I learned something today. Have a +1